# pyinstallerで作成したexeファイルに拡張子が付かず起動しない

Tags: python, python3

Python3.6の環境で、`hello`と表示する簡単なスクリプトをexe化しようとしています。

`pyinstaller test.py --onefile`を実行したところ、下記の表示が出力され、distフォルダに`.exe`の付いてないtestファイルが出力されてしまいます。
実行可能なexeファイルを出力するにはどうしたらいいでしょうか？

---

```
root@a:~/notebooks/EXE# pyinstaller test.py --onefile
111 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.4
111 INFO: Python: 3.6.4
113 INFO: Platform: Linux-4.15.0-29-generic-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid
114 INFO: wrote /root/notebooks/EXE/test.spec
116 INFO: UPX is not available.
117 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/root/notebooks/EXE', '/root/notebooks/EXE']
117 INFO: checking Analysis
117 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
117 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
124 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
126 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
6527 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
6641 INFO: Caching module hooks...
6645 INFO: Analyzing /root/notebooks/EXE/test.py
6649 INFO: Loading module hooks...
6649 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
6833 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
6834 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
7335 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
7335 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
7340 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
9923 INFO: Looking for eggs
9923 INFO: Python library not in binary dependencies. Doing additional searching...
14143 INFO: Using Python library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so.1.0
14148 INFO: Warnings written to /root/notebooks/EXE/build/test/warn-test.txt
14166 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to /root/notebooks/EXE/build/test/xref-test.html
14180 INFO: checking PYZ
14180 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
14180 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /root/notebooks/EXE/build/test/PYZ-00.pyz
14441 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) /root/notebooks/EXE/build/test/PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
14444 INFO: checking PKG
14444 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
14444 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
17288 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
17292 INFO: Bootloader /root/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyInstaller/bootloader/Linux-64bit/run
17292 INFO: checking EXE
17292 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
17292 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
17295 INFO: Appending archive to ELF section in EXE /root/notebooks/EXE/dist/test
17327 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> 113 INFO: Platform: Linux-4.15.0-29-generic-x86_64-with-debian-stretch-sid
> ```

WSL/VirtualMachine/素のLinuxのどれか、とにかくWindowsでは無い環境で実行しているようです。
PyInstallerはクロスプラットフォーム開発は出来ないとFAQの最初に出ていますので、何かしらのWindows環境で実行する必要があります。

[Frequently asked questions. pyinstaller/pyinstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/FAQ)
Google翻訳

> 1. PyInstallerをクロスコンパイラとして使えますか？
>
>    i. Linuxで実行中にWindowsバイナリをパッケージ化できますか？
>      いいえ、これはサポートされていません。これにはWineを使ってください。PyInstallerはWineでうまく動きます。メーリングリストでこのスレッドを見たいと思うかもしれません。バージョン1.4では、これをサポートする機能をいくつか組み込んでいましたが、動作は半分しかありませんでした。別のパーティションにWindowsシステムが必要になり、純粋なPythonプログラムでしか動作しません。まともなGUI（gtk、qt、wx）が欲しいとすぐに、とにかくWindowsライブラリをインストールする必要があるでしょう。だからWineを使うほうがずっと簡単です。
>
>    ii. OS Xで実行中にWindowsバイナリをパッケージ化できますか？
>      いいえ、これはサポートされていません。これをWineで試してください。
>
>    iii. Linuxで動作中にOS Xバイナリをパッケージ化できますか？
>      これは現在まったく不可能です。ごめんなさい！手助けをしたいのなら、大歓迎です。

Comment: お世話になります。実行可能な環境について勘違いがありました。早急なご回答ありがとうございました。